# Handling an onClick on a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props, react-component

Suppose I have a react app, and I have component A and component CountryCard, suppose that component A displays several times component CountryCard, as a deck of cards, by using a map instruction as in

```
{this.props.countries.map(country => <CountryCard country={country}...
```

How do I handle a click on one CountryCard?, is it enough that I use onClick, as

```
{this.props.countries.map(country => <CountryCard country={country} onClick={this.handleCountryClick(country)}...
```

or do I have to add an event listener, how do I do that?
Thanks in advance

Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just pass this.handleCountryClick to CardComponent

```
{this.props.countries.map(country => <CountryCard country={country} onCountryClick={this.handleCountryClick}...
```

then call props.onCountryClick inside of CountryCard, example:

```
<div onClick={() => this.props.onCountryClick(this.props.country)}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Events should be used as there is a call back on events:

```
onClick={e => this.handleCountryClick(country)}
```

or

```
onClick={this.handleCountryClick}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` goes on Dom elements

```
const CountryCard  = ({onClick}) => (<div onclick = {onClick}></div>)
/*maybe do a data attribute if you don't want `country` in perantasis*/
const handleCountryClick = (e) => {
    var attr = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("country")
}
```

Here's an example of a functional component

```
const CountryCard  = ({onClick, country}) => (<div country = {country} onclick = {onClick}></div>)
```

I'm just giving you an option to use data attribute so you don't have to call an event inline.

And reminding you that click events go on Dom Elements.

I don't use React classes in my work.